# ENR sets and homotopy between constant maps and homotopies

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm stumped by this homework question:
"Given an ENR space $X$, then for every points $x_0 \in X$ and open set $U \ni x$ there exists a neighborhood $V$ with $x_0 \in V \subset U$ such that the maps $i:V\rightarrow U$ and $x_0:V \rightarrow U$ are homotopic".

By definition this seems to need a lot of simple results that my mind can't memorize, I probably need to use this corollary to Borsuk's extension theorem but I'm probably missing some background to get to fulfill the hypothesis:

"If $M$ is a contractible metric space, $A$ a closed subset of $M$ and $X$ ENR, then $f:A \rightarrow X$ has an extension to $M$ if and only if it's homotopic to a constant"

Of course if I can find a closed subset $A$ of $U$ and an open set $V\subset A$ then the result follows but having only the retraction doesn't seem to cut it to find such $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned this fact from A. Dold's book *Lectures on Algebraic Topology*. If you are interested, you will find there a much more general statement.

With the ENR $X$ given, fix an embedding $j:X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, and a retraction $r:N\rightarrow X$, from an open neighbourhood $N$ of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now let $U\subseteq X$ be open and $x_0\in U$. By means of the embedding $j$ we understand $U$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the set
$$V=\{x\in U\mid (1-t)j(x)+tj(x_0)\in N\;\forall\, t\in I\}.$$
Clearly $x_0\in V$. In fact $V$ is open too, since it is the inverse image of the open set $N$ under the continuous function $U\times I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $(x,t)\mapsto (1-t)j(x)+tj(x_0)$.

To complete we define a homotopy $H:V\times I\rightarrow U$ by putting
$$H(x,t)=r\left((1-t)j(x)+tj(x_0)\right).$$